# How to use startForeground?

Tags: android, android-service

I have an android service, I am using startForeground, and do not get what I to expect to get.
I use the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("TITLE").setContentText("CONTENT").setContentInfo("INFO")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentIntent(pendIntent);

    Notification notice = builder.build();

    startForeground(startForegroundId, notice);
```

What I get next to the icon is: MyApp is running - so far so good, but them  I get the standard text: "Touch for more information or to stop..."
And - when the user clicks on the icon the App info standard dialog.

How do I change the text?
How do I run my MainActivity when the user clicks on the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write bellow code inside onStartCommand() method of your service:

```
Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Foreground Service notification?", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CurrentActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    Date dateService=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String dateString=dateService.toString().split(" ")[1]+" "+dateService.toString().split(" ")[2]+" "+dateService.toString().split(" ")[3];
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Foreground service",
            "Now foreground service running: "+dateString, pi);
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    startForeground(2337, note);
```

Comment: This is working good, BUT: Notification constructor is deprecated as well as setLatestEventInfo. what is the commended, and updated approach?