# When I kill a process in Android a Service is not restarted

Tags: android, service, process

I know that I can kill a process when I press the red square button that is in the logcat (Having the corresponding device and process selected).

[This image shows the way I use to kill an android process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFq5s.png)

However, when I do that the service is not restarted how I expect. **It calls onCreate and onDestroy and it doesn't call onStartCommand despite the fact that the onStartCommand returns START_STICKY**.

I show you my code and please if you have an idea of what the problem might be tell me

[Service code to start a music](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZssvF.png)

Comment: You should include your code in the question within a code block instead of linking to a picture.

Answer (score 0):

you need `stop service`:

```
Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
stopService(myService);
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use [Foreground Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279369/3742074) for music playback.

Also, you should try killing your app like this

> Phone Settings>Apps>your app> Force Stop

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared service inside manifest file